# Getting an authentication token for a Microsoft Custom App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I have been struggling with the same issue for a while now, i'm trying to upload a file to my MS Teams OneDrive through the Graph-API but i dont have the authorization for it.

Reading the documentation to get my Token from Microsoft has so far done nothing for me as i am new to Javascript and React, so im having extreme difficulty getting it to work right. Can anyone give me an example of what the code looks like to get the authorization token that i need to access the Graph-API?

I have registered my Microsoft app and made a client-secret that i need in order to fetch the token.

Thank you in advance!

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import * as microsoftTeams from "@microsoft/teams-js";

class Tab extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      context: {}
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Content", "text/plain");
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer {token}");

    var raw = "This works";

    var requestOptions = {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: myHeaders,
      body: raw,
      redirect: 'follow'
    }

    fetch("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/OpenSesameTest/Shared%20Documents/General/FileB.txt:/", requestOptions)
          .then(response => response.text())
          .then(result => console.log(result))
          .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
  }

componentDidMount() {
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Content", "text/plain");
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer {token}");

    var raw = "Fetch my token";

    var requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: myHeaders,
      body: raw,
      redirect: 'follow'
    }

    fetch("https://login.microsoftonline.com/openimstest/oauth2/v2.0/c7094fc6-9d30-429d-bb66-dd389295b426", requestOptions)
          .then(response => response.text())
          .then(result => console.log(result))
          .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
  }
  
  render() {  
      return (     
        <form>
          <div>
            <label>Select file to upload</label>
            <input type="file"></input>
          </div>
          <button type="submit">Upload</button>
        </form>     
      );
    }
  }

export default Tab;
```

P.S.
I know im not actually using teh file input on my page but i want to do it as simple as possible at first, i'll be happy just to succesfully upload a file through the Graph-API at the moment.
Once again thank you!

EDIT:
The the fetch im trying to use in order to get the token:

```
componentDidMount() {
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Content", "text/plain");
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer <token>");

    var raw = "This works";

    var requestOptions = {
      method: 'GET',
      grant_type: 'Unsure where to find my client_credentials',
      client_id: 'my client-id',
      scope: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
      client_secret: 'my client-secret',
      headers: myHeaders,
      body: raw,
      redirect: 'follow'
    }

    fetch("https://login.microsoftonline.com/openimstest/oauth2/v2.0/token", requestOptions)
          .then(response => response.text())
          .then(result => console.log(result))
          .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
  }
```

Im unsure where to find my client_credentials or what to put there. Also there is probably something else wrong with the fetch im trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has made a library specially for getting tokens in single pages apps. It’s called `@azure/MSAL-browser` They even made a package specially for react. [msal-react](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-react/docs/getting-started.md) this page shows a getting started on how to use this in react. This package will handle the token request for you.

### No client credentials flow

> You can do this using client secret by following the steps below. Before you continue, Note that you should not be be using the client credentials flow on the SPA Reactjs application because there is no way to secure the client secret.

The other answer should had left it with this statement. Let me explain that. The client credentials flow is for application that run server side **without** user interaction. Anyone using this flow in a client app is using it incorrectly! So I’m my opinion we should not educate people in how it might be possible to misuse an authentication flow.

Comment: And where do i put all those different pieces of code? Its not clear to me. Are they all seperate JS files? Does all of it go in my Tab.js file? All i need is a token to upload my file to the OneDrive through Graph-API, and the final piece i need is just a token. Even if i can hardcode the authentication token in my file upload fetch, im already happy. Im not worried at all about the security etc at this point. This is never going live anyway.

Comment: My react knowledge is none existing, but they also created this sample directory https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-react-samples/react-router-sample

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [Single sign-on (SSO) support for tabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso).

Follow document for creating app registration and setting up expose an API part.

Add route for all these file in your app. You might use the same route as mention in the app I shared below for folder structure.

```
<Route exact path="/signin" component={SignInPage} />
<Route exact path="/signin-simple-start" component={SignInSimpleStart} />
<Route exact path="/signin-simple-end" component={SignInSimpleEnd} />
```

Next have a look at this folder structure-> [signin](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-apps-timetally/tree/main/Source/Microsoft.Teams.Apps.Timesheet/ClientApp/src/components/signin). Here you will see three files

1. sign-in.tsx -> This file route, you need to give in the manifest. It has the button that starts the authentication flow. Also in this file only, you need to give the route of the page you want to show when authentication is successful.

   successCallback: () => {
   history.push("/yourPage");
   }
2. sign-in-start.tsx -> Here you need to call the authentication endpoint. So in the app that I shared we have backend with C# and from there we get the URL endpoint on the `line 22` and push it in history. What you can do is you can directly create that URL(*see below*) and assign it to variable result(replacing the code from line 22 to 24 with this).

`var result = https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=<client_id>&response_type=id_token token&redirect_uri=https://<app-domain>/signin-simple-end&response_mode=fragment&scope=<required-scope>&state=12345&nonce=abcde&login_hint=<user-principal-name>;`

`document.location.href = result;`

3. sign-in-end.tsx -> In this file we get all the token that we have asked in the last step. So, in order to get access token you need to add this code

   if (hashParams["access_token"]) {
   localStorage.setItem("auth.result", JSON.stringify({
   accessToken: hashParams["access_token"]
   }));
   }

in `useEffect` where we are getting other tokens. The above code checks if we get the access_token and set it in `localStorage` later on you can get it with `localStorage.getItem("auth.result")`.

*You might need to do little manipulation on `localStorage.getItem("auth.result")` in order to get the token.*

Above method get us the delegated Graph API permission, so you need to give the delegated permission in your app according to your graph call.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using client secret by following the steps below.
Before you continue, Note that you should not be be using the client credentials flow on the SPA Reactjs application because there is no way to secure the client secret.

Note that If you have to use client secret there then you should remove the interaction with Graph to the serve side and then secure your app using some other way see - this [Tutorial: Call the Microsoft Graph API in a Node.js console app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-nodejs-console) for Nodejs Secured Daemon Service authentication

For getting access token using Client Secret.

1. Add the required application permission on Azure AD for uploading the file to onedrive. In this case `Files.ReadWrite.Al`. This permission will require admin approval.
   [image]
2. Acquire an access token from Azure AD using the request below in fetch format.

   curl --location --request GET 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-id/oauth2/v2.0/token' 
   --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
   --data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' 
   --data-urlencode 'client_id=client-id' 
   --data-urlencode 'scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default' 
   --data-urlencode 'client_secret=client-secret'

As I said, client secret will not be secure when used in the Single Page Reactjs application.

The better option is to use auth code flow which will be more secure in your SPA case. Follow this for reactjs [Tutorial: Sign in users and call the Microsoft Graph API from a React single-page app (SPA) using auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-react)

This will just require:

1. Adding `Files.ReadWrite` as delegated permission on AAD
2. Signing in with a user that has access to the teams team and authenticating as them.
3. Call [PUT /groups/{group-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) where the group id is the team id.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Ive added the permissions for Files.ReadWrite.All, but im struggling with getting the fetch to work and then using the acquired token in my POST.
I will edit my original post to show you what im currently trying as a fetch, but its not working. I'm sure im doing something stupid but my biggest problem is formatting the fetch so that it works...

Comment: @7BitAscii - Grant type should be *client_credentials* only. Method should be POST. See if that works. Check if you are getting any error at console.

Comment: Have you tried following the document shared by @Danstan [Sign in users and call the Microsoft Graph API from a React](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-react)?

Comment: I downvoted this answer because no one should be using client credentials flow in a single page app. It’s bad practice. Just steer all users with questions about graph and authentication to the respected msal package. So msal-browser, msal-react or msal-angular

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT when i try it as POST im getting a TypeError: Failed to fetch. And when i check what happens im seeing a "cross origin resource sharing: missing allow origin header" any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: This is because you are using Client secret on a browser. Azure does not allow that. As I suggested, you should use auth code flow.