# getPSTNcall Javascript error Microsoft graph

Tags: javascript, token, azure-ad-msal, msal.js, microsoft-graph-api

I am able to get acesstoken with all the scope but when I add CallRecord-PstnCalls.Read.All, CallRecords.Read.All to scopes it gives me error

```
msal-browser.min.js:35 Uncaught (in promise) ServerError: invalid_client: AADSTS650053: The application 'postman' asked for scope 'CallRecord-PstnCalls.Read.All' that doesn't exist on the resource '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'. Contact the app vendor.
Trace ID: f7f4e4a5-078d-4aaf-bee7-c0c61f9f8e00
Correlation ID: 66ccba3c-fce0-4c40-8b00-83060b9defc3
Timestamp: 2021-12-28 13:24:30Z
```

the following is my code.Please help me my boss needs this done today.I have all the permission in azure for PSTN

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`)
});
async function run(){

    const config = {
        auth: {
            clientId: '1be18c1a-5a3d-43ac-a953-5e04c6b8a93f',
            authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/',
            redirectUri: 'http://localhost:8080'
        }
    };
    var client = new msal.PublicClientApplication(config);
    
    var loginRequest = {
        scopes: ['CallRecord-PstnCalls.Read.All','CallRecords.Read.All']
    };
    let loginResponse = await client.loginPopup(loginRequest);
    console.log('Login Response', loginResponse);
    var tokenRequest = {
        scopes: ['CallRecord-PstnCalls.Read.All','CallRecords.Read.All' ],
        account: loginResponse.account
    };
    let tokenResponse = await client.acquireTokenSilent(tokenRequest);
    console.log('Token Response', tokenResponse);
    let payload = await fetch("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/callRecords/getPstnCalls(fromDateTime=2019-11-01,toDateTime=2019-12-01)", {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + tokenResponse.accessToken
        }
    });
    let json = await payload.json();
    console.log('Graph Response', json);
}
```

Comment: Did you added as Application permission and grant admin consent as well for the app?

Comment: yes i have all the application permission

Comment: Did you try same with Postman is it working there? If not can you try once? Here how to [get access token without user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?view=graph-rest-beta) and then add token while sending request via Postman

Comment: i am able to get acesss token via postman  but not by code :(

Comment: Have a look at this post. Can you try one of the method mention there - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69167508/getting-an-authentication-token-for-a-microsoft-custom-app

Answer (score 1):

Mainly this issue occurs if the scopes are not added in your App registration. Please make sure that it is added to correct app registration and permission is granted by an admin.

Please follow this link to call an API using MSAL -
[Acquire token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-acquire-token?tabs=javascript2).

For you further reference we are adding a sample link where we are using MSAL flow to call Graph.
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/v-nikija/tab-sso-obo-update/samples/tab-sso/nodejs/src/server/tabs.js

Please refer above sample and in authority can you specify the tenantId -
`authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/${your_tenant_Id}"`.